# GoogleSheets: How to return most recent record matching 2 columns with Query of Filter

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, multiple-conditions

I use a table to manage supplies. I would like to get a new table with the most recent record of each data if "Location" and "Nb" are unique.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pAPv3r3ghRpWUAmpQipcd5DIaovoGIAdhE5arrSMM7I/edit?usp=sharing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCggo.jpg)

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT({A2:D\ ROW(A2:A)\ A2:A&B2:B}; 5; 0); 9^9; 2; 6; 1); 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0 ! It is working in this spreadsheet but when I use it in another one it returns #ERROR! Do you know why ?

Comment: I fixed it! I dont know how but it working wel now. Thanks a lot!!